# Import multiple sheets from excel spreadsheet into r

Tags: r, dataframe, import, readxl

I want to import multiple sheets, selected by a common string in the sheet name, from a single .xlsx file and concatenate them into single data frame. For example, if I have an excel file ('data.xlsx') with worksheets named samples1, samples2, samples3, controls1, controls2, controls3. I want to make a list of the worksheet names, such as:

```
sheet_list <- lapply(excel_sheets('data.xlsx'), read_excel, path = 'data.xlsx')
```

Then, I want to import all sheets that contain 'samples' in the name and bind them into a data frame called 'samples'. How can I accomplish this efficiently?

Comment: You may also want to check [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) package as it provides a lot of handy functions for reading data from Excel, including workbooks table objects, and exporting to Excel as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close!  You can use `lapply` and such to accomplish this using base R, but I routinely perform tasks like this using the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)    

sheets <- excel_sheets('data.xlsx')

sample_sheets <- sheets[grepl("samples", sheets)]

sheet_df <- map_dfr(sample_sheets, ~read_excel(path = 'data.xlsx', sheet = .x), id = .x)
```

This does:

1. Get the names of the sheets.
2. Use `grepl` to subset the sheets to only those containing "samples" in the name.
3. Use `map_dfr` to iterate over the sample sheets, reading each one in and assigning an id column equal to the name of the sheet, then bind all the results together by rows and return a data frame.

Comment: When I applied for my data, I received an error message `Error in read_excel(path = "covid19_mph.xlsx", sheet = .x, id = .x) :     unused argument (id = .x)`

Comment: the `id` argument should be part of `map_dfr` rather than `read_excel`.   Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
path <- "C:\\your_path_here\\test.xlsx"

path %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(read_excel, path = path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(readxl)
list <- excel_sheets("path_to_excel.xlsx")
list_samples <- list[grepl("samples", list)]
df <- rbind(lapply(list_samples, function(x) read_excel("path_to_excel.xlsx", sheet = x)))
```