# R: Use Regex to Import Specific Sheets from Multiple Excel Files

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, purrr, readxl

I have a group of Excel files with multiple sheets which don’t follow a standard naming convention. I want to create a single data frame from specific sheets containing the keyword *'frame'*.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

# Sample Excel File 1
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
data_frame2 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
list_of_datasets1 <- list("df" = df1, "date_frame" = data_frame2)
write.xlsx(list_of_datasets1, file = "writeXLSX1.xlsx")

# Sample Excel File 2
df3 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
data_frame4 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
list_of_datasets2 <- list("date_frames" = df3, "dfs" = data_frame4)
write.xlsx(list_of_datasets2, file = "writeXLSX2.xlsx")

# Create List of Excel Files
excel_file_list <- list.files(pattern = "writeXLSX\\d*.xlsx", full.names = T)
```

I'd like to be able to do this using a regex with `purr` like this:

```
df_bind <- excel_file_list %>%
  map_dfr(~read_excel(.x, sheet = grepl("frame", .x)))
```

The closest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925310/5195054) I found works fine with a single file. However, I can't quite figure out how to extract the sheet names correctly when they're in a list.

Comment: Have you tried 'readxl::excel_sheets' to extract the sheet names to use directly in the map function?

Comment: Yeah, but again wasn't sure on how to exit the loop error when it requested a path string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
excel_file_list %>% 
      map_dfr(~ read_excel(.x, sheet = which(str_detect(excel_sheets(.x), 'frame'))))
```

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I'm looking for. Can you just change the `map` function to `map_dfr` and I'll accept it.